# jQuery's get() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a **.cgi** file to get some hardware information and now, I would like to get those information from another HTML page in the same domain with the jQuery's `get()` function. I tried to do this with this piece of code :

```
var cgiContent = '';

$.get("http://localhost/cgi-bin/CPU.cgi", function(data)
{   
    cgiContent = data;
});
```

But it doesn't work and I have no idea why... When I look at the Firefox's debugger, `cgiContent = ''` and `data` is still undefined.

I'm new here, please tell me if you need more information about anything to answer me.

Best regards,
Nittak

Comment: Is the file loaded from the same domain? (i.e. `http://localhost/`). Is the success callback executed at all? Does the network tab show any problems with the request/response?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the URL directly in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can accessing to the URL directly in my browser and the file is loaded from the same domain.

Comment: [07:41:05.696] GET http://localhost/cgi-bin/CPU.cgi [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 6ms] Felix Kling, is that your are talking about ?

Comment: probably a SOP problem. Since (you claim) you are on the same domain, just omit the protocol and domain name, just write `cgi-bin/CPU.cgi`. Firefox may show a 200, while still actually failing to get the content due to SOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a Same Origin Problem (SOP) problem. Firefox may show a 200, while still actually failing to get the content due to SOP.
Since (you claim) you are on the same domain, just omit the protocol and domain name and just write `$.get("cgi-bin/CPU.cgi"` and see if it works with that.

Also add a `console.log` to your success function to see if it really is executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, Firefox seems complete the protocol and the domain when I omit it. I also add a console.log but nothing is displayed in the console...

Comment: @Nittak every browser does that. It's the recommmended way to specify urls, btw.

Comment: Ok, but my problem is not solved yet, it's makes me crazy ! x)

Comment: What exactly should be returned? Sure, it's not perhaps an error in your script?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong from the beginning and my pages are not in the same domain. There are both local files, it is possible that they are not in the same domain. In that case, what can I do ?

Comment: I add this line : console.log(cgiContent); But nothing appears in the console.

Comment: "[Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js Line: 6"]" So, I'm not in the same domain, right ?

Comment: @Nittak correct. THat's a SOP error. Try to use a non-localhost installation if it works there.